# How to compute this "differential sequence" of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, delay-differential-equations

Given a real function $f$, define the following sequences of functions:

- $f_0(x) = f(x)$;
- $f_{i+1}'(x) = [f_i(x+1)-f_i(x-1)]/2$.

Some simple examples are:

- If $f(x)=x$, then $f_i(x)=x$ for all $i\geq 0$ (up to an additive constant; note that adding a constant to $f_i$ does not affect $f_{i+1}$).
- Similarly, if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f_i(x)=x^2$ for all $i\geq 0$.
- The "pattern" breaks at 3: if $f(x)=x^3$, then $f_i(x) = x^3 + i\cdot x$.

But for some functions, computing $f_i$ is much harder. I am particualrly interested in $f(x)=1/x$. I get $f_1(x) = (\ln(x+1)-\ln(x-1))/2$, but from this point on, the sequence becomes much harder to compute.

QUESTIONS:

- Is there a simple algorithm to compute $f_i(x)$ for a general $f$?
- If not, is there a simple expression for $f_i(x)$ for the case when $f(x)=1/x$, or at least an expression that approximates $f_i(x)$?
- Does this sequence I made up have a known name?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful to try to consider what we obtain for functions $f(x)$ represented as a series of powers of $x$ or $(x-a)$.

Comment: We can get rid of the ambiguity with the additive constant if we require that $f_i(0)=0$ for each nonnegative integer $i$.

Comment: For $f(x)=1/x$ the function $f'_i(x)$ is undefined in some points already for $i=1$. So I expect that $f_i'(x)$ can be undefined for some integer $x$ with $|x|\le i$.

Comment: I guess to take into account cases $x<1$, for $f(x)=1/x$ we should have $f_1(x)=(\ln |x+1|-\ln|x-1|)/2$ and $x\ne\pm 1$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes, we can remove points in which $f_i$ is not defined.

Comment: Formally with a symbolic processor like MATHEMATICA we can obtain some results. Try for instance `n = 5; f[x_] := 1/x; seq = {f[x]};Do[solf = DSolve[D[df[x], x] == f[x + 1] - f[x - 1], df, x][[1]]; f[x_] := df[x] /. solf;AppendTo[seq, f[x]], {n}] ;seq`

Comment: Good but weird question imo, I might use this idea somehow ...

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, then the convolution product
$$Tf := f * \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$$
is well defined. Moreover, $$Tf(x) = \frac{1}{2}(F(x+1)-F(x-1))/2,$$
where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

For every positive integer $n$, $T^nf := f * u^{*n}$, where $u^*n$ is the $n$-fold convolution product of $u:=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$, equivalently the density of the sum of $n$ independent random variables which are unifom on $[-1,1]$.

The convolution product $u^{*n}$ can be computed explicitly since
for every $n \ge 2$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}^{*n}(s) = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k \frac{(s-k)_+^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: You define $T f(x)$ once at line 4, and then give a different definition at line 6. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes it was a typo. In corrected $Tf$ into $T^nf$ at line 6.

Comment: So what is the formula to compute $f_i$? Is it: $f_i =T^n f$?

Comment: $f_n=T^nf$, because the recursion relation you study is $f_{i+1}=Tf_i$ (up to additive constants).

Comment: Not exactly: as $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$, the recursion relation is actually $f_{i+1} = T[f_i']$.

Comment: If $f_{i+1}'(x) = [f_i(x+1)-f_i(x-1)]/2$ for all real number $x$, then, up to an additive constant, we have  $f_{i+1}(x) = [F_i(x+1)-F_i(x-1)]/2 = Tf(x)$.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas. Let $X=C_0(\mathbb R)$ be the space of continuous functions $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(0)=0$. For each $f\in X$ and $x\in\mathbb R$ put $$T(f)(x)=\frac 12\int_0^x (f(t+1)-f(t-1))dt.$$
Then $T$ should be a linear operator from $X$ to $X$ such that $f_i=T^i(f)$ for each $f\in X$ and each nonnegative integer $i$ (here we assume that $T^0$ is the identity operator).

So it can be useful to calculate $T(f)$ for some functions $f\in X$. For instance, for each natural $n$, we have $$T(x^n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \frac 1{n-2k}\cdot {n \choose 2k+1} x^{n-2k}.$$

Maybe the operator $T$ will be continuous when we endow $X$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb R$. Maybe then we shall be able to linearly extend the above formula to functions $f(x)\in X$ represented as a series of powers of $x$ with the infinite radius of convergence.